# Excel Interop error

Tags: c#, winforms, com-interop, excel-interop

I'm having a problem with running an application I made on another computer. This is the error message I'm getting:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154`

I searched it on Google, and found out that it means that I need to register that specific component in regedit, but I don't know how to do it, or where to find that component, so please help me.

I used C# in VS 2010 to make my application. One more thing, I don't know if it matters - I installed this application on 3 different computers, and this is the only one that gives me that error - it is a HP all-in-One computer.

Comment: is Excel installed on that computer ? if yes, is the excel version different from the other computers ?

Comment: Regasm. Check it out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: There seems to be some problem with Excel (or Office as a whole) so we will try to reinstall it, and see if the same error appears. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

That's the guid for Microsoft Excel's Application class.  Two very basic reasons you'll get this error:

- Microsoft Office is not installed on that machine
- The machine has a 64-bit operating system and you installed the 32-bit version of Office.  You have to force your program to run in 32-bit mode.  Project + Properties, Build tab, change the Platform target setting to x86
- The machine has a 64-bit operating system and you installed the 64-bit version of Office 2010.  Same fix as above but now you have to make sure to select the AnyCPU target.